# typo3/cms-tstemplate 10.0.x-dev requires typo3/cms-core 10.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[10.0.x-dev]

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-9.x

Hello i am trying to install the latest lts of typo3.
I am new to typo3 and just getting into it.

I chose composer since it it the easyest way to install.

On the website it says i need to use

```
require typo3/minimal
```

But when i try to add any other extenstions like

```
typo3/cms-tstemplate
```

I get this error.

```
Using version ^10.0@dev for typo3/cms-tstemplate
Search for a package:
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install typo3/cms-core 10.0.x-dev|don't install typo3/cms-core 9.5.x-dev
    - don't install typo3/cms-core 10.0.x-dev|remove typo3/cms-core 9.5.x-dev
    - don't install typo3/cms-core 10.0.x-dev|don't install typo3/cms-core 9.5.x-dev
    - typo3/cms-tstemplate 10.0.x-dev requires typo3/cms-core 10.0.*@dev -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[10.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for typo3/cms-tstemplate ^10.0@dev -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-tstemplate[10.0.x-dev].
    - Installation request for typo3/cms-core (locked at 9.5.x-dev) -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[9.5.x-dev].
```

So what version do i need to adjust now, it is a bit confusing to read.

EDIT:

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "typo3/minimal": "9.5"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "email": "test"
        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Cmd line:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\test> composer require typo3/minimal:^9.5
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Generating class alias map file
Inserting class alias loader into main autoload.php file
C:\xampp\htdocs\test> composer require typo3/cms-tstemplate:^9.5
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install typo3/cms-core v9.5.0|don't install typo3/cms-core 9.5.x-dev
    - don't install typo3/cms-core v9.5.0|remove typo3/cms-core 9.5.x-dev
    - don't install typo3/cms-core v9.5.0|don't install typo3/cms-core 9.5.x-dev
    - typo3/cms-tstemplate v9.5.0 requires typo3/cms-core 9.5.0 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[v9.5.0].
    - Installation request for typo3/cms-tstemplate 9.5 -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-tstemplate[v9.5.0].
    - Installation request for typo3/cms-core (locked at 9.5.x-dev) -> satisfiable by typo3/cms-core[9.5.x-dev].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest stable LTS version of TYPO3 is 9.5. Version 10.0 hasn't been released yet so you will only get at development version.

So I'd suggest to start with

```
composer require typo3/minimal:"^9.5"
```

For all other TYPO3 system extensions you can do it the same way:

```
composer require typo3/cms-tstemplate:"^9.5"
```

Comment: Hey i have in my .json ```typo3/minimal": "^9.5@dev``` and i cant require tstemplate 9.5. I get the same error. Is there a difference between 9.5 and 9.5@dev ?

Comment: I've just tested it again, for me even `composer require typo3/minimal` and `composer require typo3/cms-tstemplate` work perfect to get TYPO3 9.5. Can you post your complete `composer.json`?

Comment: Hey i edited the question could you please check again. I also tried deleting the lock and installing again. Same error output.

Comment: I assume that you've created the composer.json manually? Just start in a blank directory with `composer require typo3/minimal` or remove `"minimum-stability": "dev"` from your composer.json.

Comment: Hey, thank you removing dev did the trick, but may i ask why ?

Comment: I assume that you prefer stable versions. If you minimum-stability to dev, composer will prefer dev packages over older but stable packages. See here for details: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability